# Python setuptools: __init__.py does not call declare_namespace()

Tags: python, setuptools, zope, zodb, namespace-package

I am trying to install the zope2.zodbbrowser 0.2 package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope2.zodbbrowser/0.2). The setup script fails with the following error:

```
Namespace package problem: zope2 is a namespace package, but its
__init__.py does not call declare_namespace()! Please fix it.
(See the setuptools manual under "Namespace Packages" for details.)
```

The relevant section in the manual seems to be this one here: https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#namespace-packages

However, I am not familiar with the internals of setuptools and I could not resolve the problem with the help of the manual. How can I resolve this namespace problem to successfully install the package?

For your reference, the source code of ~/zodbbrowser/src/zope2.zodbbrowser/zope2/__ init__.py is:

```
# this is a namespace package
try:
    import pkg_resources
    pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)
except ImportError:
    import pkgutil
    __path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

Comment: have you tried installing with pip? Are you using python2.6?

Comment: Yes I have tried pip but it says that requirements are already up-to-date (without actually installing the package). I am using python 2.7.

Comment: That package is for python 2.6. what os are you using?

Comment: Is there any possibility to run it under python 2.7? My OS is Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.

Comment: there is a newer package here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zodbbrowser. You seem to have to installed already with pip, make sure you are using the correct pip for python2.7

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you to use the `declare_namespace()` function, so it seems to be possible to make it work that way.

But you should probably use an implicit namespace package and remove the `__init__.py` entirely. Namespace packages generally do not have one because they can conflict with `__init__.py` from another namespace package with the same arborescence.

For example, if you have the `zope2.a` namespace:

```
zope2/__ init__.py
zope2/a/__init__.py
```

And the `zope2.b` namespace:

```
zope2/__ init__.py
zope2/b/__init__.py
```

The result after install the two would be:

```
zope2/__ init__.py <= Setuptools cannot know which file to take
zope2/a/__init__.py
zope2/b/__init__.py
```

See the Python documentation:

> All that is required to create a native namespace package is that you just omit **init**.py from the namespace package directory.

https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/